# Setting up UART with STM32L4RGTx

Tags: stm32, uart, serial, gpio, stm32cubemx

The prompt here is to debug the issue with UART setup on the STM32 chipset. I've followed a couple of online blogs to understand and setup the UART interface.

**I want to transmit (only) a dataframe (String) of a defined length.**

The UART TX and RX pins are connected to PA0 and PA1, i.e PIN14 and PIN15.
There are 3 functions which are important here.

1. MX_GPIO_Init()
2. HAL_UART_Transmit()
3. UART Structure setup.
4. MX_GPIO_INIT()

```
 static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
    {
          GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
          /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
          __UART4_CLK_ENABLE();
            __GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
          __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
              __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
          __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE(); 
            
            //Configure PA9 for Magnetic Sensor input
            GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
            GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;//GPIO_NOPULL
          HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct); 
             //configure for  LEDs
            GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3 | GPIO_PIN_4;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
            GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;//GPIO_NOPULL
          HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct); 
            
            
            /*Configure GPIO pin : PA10*/
          GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
            GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;//GPIO_NOPULL
          HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct); 
        
          /*Configure GPIO pin : PA8 */
          GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
          HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
            
              /*Configure GPIO pins : PB13 PB14 PB15 */
          GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11 | GPIO_PIN_12 | GPIO_PIN_13;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
          HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
            
            GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
            GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
          HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
            
            // PC6, PC7, PC8 and PC9 configured as input for magnetic sensor read function
            GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_7 | GPIO_PIN_8 | GPIO_PIN_9;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
            GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL ;
          HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
         
          /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            
            
            
            GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_15;
            GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
            GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
            GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
            
            HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
            
            GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_14;
            GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
            HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
            
            HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(RCC_IRQn, 0, 0);
          HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(RCC_IRQn);
        
          HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, 1, 0);
          HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);
        
        }
```

This particular function has been called from a seperate file and is called in main.c in the main loop.

The main loop.

```
int main(void)
{
  /* Initialize the hardware */
    Init_Sys();
    startADC();
    uart4.Instance = UART4;
    uart4.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
    uart4.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    uart4.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    uart4.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    uart4.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    uart4.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    uart4.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    
    
    HAL_UART_Init(&uart4);

        
    intFrame();
  /* Infinite Loop */
  while (1)
  { 
     
     char data[4] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'o'};
     HAL_StatusTypeDef return_code = HAL_UART_Transmit(&uart4, (uint8_t*)data, 4, 100 );  
    }
}
```

The above piece of code is from the main.c.

The code compiles correctly, the includes are defined well, I flashed it, but the data doesn't seem to appear on the serial monitor.

Things I tried.

1. Debugging the code with the debugger.
2. Connect the pins to a serial converter.

When I try to debug the code with the debugger, the `HAL_StatusTypeDef` says `HAL_OK`but I dont see the data on the serial monitor.

What can I do to correct this? Is there something to do with the GPIO Init or with the UART structure definitions gone wrong?

Comment: I don't get it. How can PA0 and PA1 be PIN14 and PIN15 if they are PIN0 and PIN1? And since GPIO pin is configured for alternate function to be UART pins, where do you enable clocks for AFIO?

Comment: You're not configuring PA0 or PA1 anywhere in your `MX_GPIO_Init()` function. The only 2 pins you're configuring for 'Alternate Function Mode' are PC14 & PC15, but even there you're not configuring *which* alternate function.

Comment: @Justme could you please elaborate on the defects you see? and how I can get around them? I'm new to ARM and these are one of the first few projects I've started with.

Comment: @brhans could you please explain what defects you observe and how I can get around them?